# How to have fixed div height irrespective of image height within it

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, padding

I have a row with three columns. I want to have a image on each column's divs with same height irrespective of image size in each div.

I want the images to get resized with in a div. But I get different size of divs as the image size of `myImage1.png`, `myImage2.png` and `myImage3.png` is different.

This is happening because I have fixed padding in my 'bg' class. Can somebody help me to fix this?

This is my HTML and CSS code:

```
<div class="row IDE_container">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="bg">
            <img src="myImage1.png" class="IDE_div" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <div class="circle_bg circle_bg_sm">
            <img src="myImage2.png" class="IDE_div" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="circle_bg">
            <img src="myImage3.png" class="IDE_div" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bg {
    background-color: #ededed;
    border-radius: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 35% 5%;
    width: max-content;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px #DDD;
}

.IDE_div {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
}

.IDE_container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to use `pseudo-elements` on `img` elements. That's not possible.  Also, `.IDE_div` class is not a good name for a class added on an image :)

Comment: @MihaiT Updated my code without pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 2):

> **For various kind of images, so can use `object-fit` property.**

Add the CSS like this:

```
.IDE_div{
width: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
height: 300px; /* only if you want fixed height */
}

<div class="col-3">
    <div class="circle_bg">
        <img src="myImage3.png" class="IDE_div" />
    </div>
</div>
```

You will find the details about `object-fit` and `object-position` here : https://css-tricks.com/on-object-fit-and-object-position/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a height or max-height on the divs containing the images, or they will adapt to the height of their content (the images). As you've set the images to take up 100% width and height, and haven't constrained their parents, they will get as large as they can based on the original image size.

So, for example :

```
.IDE_container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;

  div.col-3 {

    div {
      height: 200px;

      .IDE_div {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

        &::before {
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          width: var(--val);
          padding-bottom: var(--val);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          z-index: -1;
          border-radius: 50%;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could give all containers the same class (e.g. fixed-height-bg) to style them more easily.

Also note: You don't need to give your columns individual classes for different screen sizes, as they always take up the same proportion. So, you can just use

```
 <div class="col-3">
        <div class="circle_bg">
            <img src="myImage3.png" class="IDE_div" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

EDITED to add: if you want the images to maintain their proportions, you need to change your css to look like this:

```
img {
  height: 100%; /* height of the parent container if specified, or of the image itself */
  width: auto; /* will maintain the proportions of the image */
}
```

You can also switch those values, to height: auto; width: 100%; if you want the images to take the full width.

Comment: This did not help. It enlarges all the image to 200px. That is not the requirement. I want to maintain the proportions of each image. Pls help.

Comment: Right, that's because I put the arbitrary number of 200px for height. Sorry I didn't make that clear. You could add any number that you want. 

If you want the images to maintain their proportions, you can work it this way: 

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

(or the other way around). But if you don't restrain the height of their parent container, they will not be "even". 

If you just want the parent containers to have the same height regardless of image size, you can - well - give them whatever height you want in css.